# JavaFx - Interactive sort application

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

I'm working on a interactive sort application. I must represent numbers as rectangles, and for example, when the sorting algorithm is running, when two numbers are swapped, the rectangles must be swapped. I want to do this with animations. How can I swap the rectangles? I currently testing this using transition but I have some problems. I have two rectangles in a group. When I try to swap the rectangles, both will meet in the middle and stop. Here's the code:

```
    Rectangle r1 = rectangles.get(numbers[0]);
    Rectangle r2 = rectangles.get(numbers[1]);

    TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition();

    translateTransition.setNode(r1);
    translateTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition.setFromX(r1.getX());
    translateTransition.setToX(r2.getX());

    TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();

    translateTransition2.setNode(r2);
    translateTransition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translateTransition2.setFromX(r2.getX());
    translateTransition2.setToX(r1.getX());
    translateTransition2.play();

    translateTransition.play();
```

I need a pane similar with canvas. I need to be able to set the rectangles coordinates.

Comment: you want to swap it with some animation or just change colors?

Comment: I want some animations. I don't want an instant swap.

Answer (score 2):

`TranslateTransition` works with `translateX` property of the Node. Thus, if you positioned rectangles using `setLayout`, `relocate` or just constructor parameter TranslateTransition wouldn't work for you.

You either need to start using `translateX` coordinates or use `Timeline` instead of `TranslateTransition`.

You can read more about layout and translate in [JavaDoc for layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty)

Here is translateX based swap example:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED);
    final Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.BLUE);

    // note I use translate to position rectangles
    r1.setTranslateX(50);
    r2.setTranslateX(250);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Move it");
    btn.relocate(100, 100);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            double x1 = r1.getTranslateX();
            double x2 = r2.getTranslateX();

            TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition();
            translateTransition.setNode(r1);
            translateTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
            translateTransition.setToX(x2);

            TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();
            translateTransition2.setNode(r2);
            translateTransition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
            translateTransition2.setToX(x1);

            translateTransition2.play();
            translateTransition.play();
        }
    });

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, r1, r2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 350);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```